# When controls are hidden/disabled in the Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, windows-forms-designer, design-time

What are some of the criteria for the controls get disabled in the Visual Studio 2010 Toolbox?

If the user enables "Show All" all the controls in the Toolbox are shown, but some of them are disabled. What causes the controls to be disabled?

One reason could be if the control is cannot be dragged-and-dropped on the design surface, depending on what type of document is open.

However, I noticed that, my .NET 3.5 controls are disabled, when developing a 3.5 windows forms application in Visual Studio 2010. What could be causing this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Datte

Comment: The ToolboxItemFilterAttribute class is the selector.  It is inherited so as long as you derived from the correct base class, your control should be filtered properly.

Answer (score 1):

i solved this by selecting project -> properties , in application tab , selecting .NET framework client profile to .Net Framework. the controls are enabled after this.

It seems to be the target framework which causes this to happen.

hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

this depend of your project, if this target .net 2 you cannot see the .net 4 controls is very common with third party controls with target 2.0.3.5 etc

my experience was with third party controls.

Comment: I am trying to use a 3.5 control in 3.5 project!